# Can I hook up an external GPS to Android devices without a built-in GPS?

Tags: gps, external-gps

I know there's a number of [solutions](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bluetooth-gps-provider/de.mobilej.btgps) that allow you to use a Bluetooth-enabled external GPS antenna but what if you don't have Bluetooth?  Does anyone know of a way to connect a USB GPS antenna to an Android device?

**A little background: I just ordered this cheap [resistive screen tablet](http://www.walgreens.com/store/c/maylong-7-inch-m-150-universe-tablet-powered-by-android/ID=prod6047418-product) primarily to be a less expensive dedicated Kindle/Nook Reader but I'm also thinking up other ways I can use this thing.  One way I was thinking was as GPS unit mounted on my dash, only problem... no GPS.*

Comment: Off-topic, but I'd love to hear from you about you how like that tablet sometime.

Comment: Yeah, I'll report back as soon as it arrives.  I'm still trying to figure out if I should have dropped the extra $70-80 for the Augen or the Cherrypad that are running 2.1.  Basically, this was the cheapest way I could find out how bad a resistive screen actually is with Android.

Comment: I'm cancelling my order on the Cherrypad.  It still hasn't shipped and I'm going down to Sears right now to get this badboy: http://www.sears.com/shc/s/p_10153_12605_00382001000P

Comment: @Matt What was the outcome of this?

Comment: If it has data or voice, you should be able to use triangulation from cell towers to get a rough location.

Comment: @Ryan Conrad: I returned that tablet and got and Archos 70 which still applies to this situation.  I haven't found a suitable solution yet.  The Archos has bluetooth and like I said I have seen Bluetooth enabled GPS antennas and there are some apps in the market that enable you to use an external BT antenna but I explored that route because I'm holding out for a USB solution which I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Bluetooth is the only way to do this.

In order to be able to do this via USB the device would need to support USB-OTG (basically be capable of acting as a USB host); given that you are excluding Bluetooth, I doubt there would be a device with USB-OTG but without Bluetooth. You'd obviously need a GPS capable of sending data over USB, as well.